# Confirming success of Elasticsearch admin request from Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have some code in my Java project which administrates indices in an Elasticsearch cluster:

```
indexAdminClient.prepareCreate("myindex").get();
```

This apparently returns a generic class extending ActionResponse, which by my reading does not provide a way to confirm whether the call was successful. What is the appropriate way to confirm a successful API call to Elasticsearch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
indexAdminClient.prepareCreate("myindex").execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: I don't see how to check the return of this call for success either. It appears to be an unrestricted generic.

Comment: That returns a `CreateIndexResponse` which should have an `isAcknowledged()` method.

Comment: Ah, I see. .get() also has an isAcknowledged() method; does it behave differently?

Comment: It's actually the same thing, `get()` calls `execute().actionGet()`